# Has anyone studied the quasimetric induced by the KL divergence?

Tags: probability, statistics, metric-spaces, information-theory, information-geometry

Recall that, for probability measures $p$ and $q$ on a finite set $X$, the [Kullback-Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence)
$$
D(p||q) = \sum_{x\in X} p(x) \log \dfrac{p(x)}{q(x)}
$$
is famously *not* a metric, in particular it does not satisfy a triangle inequality.

However, in principle one could look at the following quantity
$$
d(p,q) := \inf_{n\in \Bbb{N}} \inf_{p_1,\dots,p_n} \Big( d(p,p_1) + d(p_1,p_2) + \dots + d(p_n, q) \Big) ,
$$
which *does* satisfy the triangle inequality, it is the largest quasimetric which is less or equal than $D(p||q)$.

Has this quantity been studied anywhere? Is it trivial (i.e. zero)?

Comment: It might interest you that the square root of the Jenson Shannon divergence (which is defined only using the KL divergence) is a metric on infinite spaces also.